# Error in eval(exprs[i], envir) : object 'confint.default' not found

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-package

**R package Installation error**

*englianhu 3 Jul 17*

`install.packages()` and `update.packages()` both facing error as showing below :

```
Error in eval(exprs[i], envir) : object 'confint.default' not found
Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Downloading GitHub repo tidyverse/tidyverse@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                            
2: CRAN packages only             
3: None                           
4: stringi (1.6.2 -> 1.7.3) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates: 1
stringi (1.6.2 -> 1.7.3) [CRAN]
Rcpp    (NA    -> 1.0.7) [CRAN]
isoband (NA    -> 0.2.5) [CRAN]
Skipping 1 packages ahead of CRAN: data.table
Installing 3 packages: stringi, Rcpp, isoband
Installing packages into ‘/usr/lib/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/stringi_1.7.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7599615 bytes (7.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 7.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rcpp_1.0.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2941808 bytes (2.8 MB)
```

...
...

Believe that using different download method in both `install.packages()` and `update.packages()`. Somebody take a look? Studying Coursera Course as time being

source : [**RStudio Community** - R package Installation error](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-package-installation-error/110251)

[image: confint.default]

Comment: this is very confusing; it looks like the `confint.default` error is from some code you ran previously? (It should have nothing to do with package installation ...)

Comment: As Ben Bolker points out, this is probably from starting R/RStudio in a directory where you've saved previous work, possibly your Coursera stuff. Start R/RStudio in a new directory and run your `install.packages(` and `update.packages(` there.

Comment: Wonder if because adjusted arguments on `install.packages(methods, inst_opt) `https://community.rstudio.com/uploads/default/original/3X/a/2/a2238a3af3819e3408c270371760ffb0979a2d8e.png

Comment: The error still been there without `envar`, https://d.cosx.org/d/422387-robject-confintdefault-not-found/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the error still there but at least `:$ sudo su - -c "R -e \"devtools::update_packages()\""` make update and install packages working fine.

https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-package-installation-error/110251/7?u=englianhu